# polyfit error 1d or 2d array needed for y

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

[Click here to see traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ubp0I.png)

I have the following question:

Write a Python program to generate data that uses the sum of a random variable (which has a Gaussian distribution) and a 4th-degree polynomial equation (3x4+x3+3x2+4x+5). Using least squares polynomial fit, curve the generated data using a model until your model can accurately predict all values

with the following start on the question:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def mainFunc():
    poly_coeff=[3,1,3,4,5]
    poly=np.poly1d(poly_coeff)
    print(poly)
    y = poly(random.randint(0,10)) + min(10,max(0,random.gauss(2,3)))
    x=np.arange(-10,10)
    curvefit=np.polyfit(x,y,4)
    y_new=np.polyfit(curvefit,x)
    plt.plot(x,y, '-or')
    plt.plot(x,y_new, '-b')
    plt.show()


mainFunc()
```

Can anyone help with the array error that is being generated?

Comment: Please show the full traceback

Comment: What's the shape of `x` and `y2`?  Of `curvefit` if it gets that far?

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the traceback in the post. Or at least I think I did.